# undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera10InitCameraEi' with 1394cmu on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, undefined-reference

I'm using this program with Opencv and 1394cmu to grab a video stream from firewire.
but when I compile the project I get some errors. the libraries are correctly imported in eclipse in fact the object's method are seen and the two ddl are also correctly imported so I have no idea qhere is the problem

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera10InitCameraEi'   
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera12AcquireImageEv' 
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera12SetVideoModeEm' 
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera14SetVideoFormatEm'   
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera16StopImageCaptureEv' 
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera17SetVideoFrameRateEm'    
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera21StartImageAcquisitionEv'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera6getRGBEPhm'  
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394Camera9CheckLinkEv' 
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11C1394CameraC1Ev' 



 #include "1394Camera.h"

// adjust parameters to your needs
#define CAM_RES_WIDTH 640
#define CAM_RES_HEIGHT 480
#define CAM_RES_CHANNELS 3

//camera object of the 1394CMU driver
C1394Camera Camera;


 int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // several checks if camera is connected and can be initialized as well as setting
    // of camera properties and starting of image aquisition
    if(Camera.CheckLink() != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("\nNo Link.");
            return -1;
    }
    if(Camera.InitCamera() != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("\nInitialization failed.");
            return -1;
    }
    if(Camera.SetVideoFormat(0) != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("\nCould not set video format.");
            return -1;
    }
    if(Camera.SetVideoMode(5) != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("\nCould not set video mode.");
            return -1;
    }
    if(Camera.SetVideoFrameRate(4) != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("\nCould not set frame rate.");
            return -1;
    }
    if(Camera.StartImageAcquisition() != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("\nCould not start image acquisation.");
            return -1;
    }

  //give camera a chance to inititalize and adjust before starting frame aquisition
    cvWaitKey(1000); 

    cvNamedWindow( "Source",1);     

    IplImage *Image = cvCreateImage( cvSize(CAM_RES_WIDTH, CAM_RES_HEIGHT), 8,      CAM_RES_CHANNELS);

  //aquire frame from camera
    if(Camera.AcquireImage() != CAM_SUCCESS)
    {       
            printf("\nCould not acquire image.");
            return 1;
    }

  //read frame from internal CMU1394 storage to buffer
    Camera01.getRGB((unsigned char*)(Image->imageData), (CAM_RES_WIDTH*CAM_RES_HEIGHT*3));

    cvShowImage("Source", Image);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    Camera.StopImageCapture();
    cvReleaseImage(&Image);
    cvDestroyWindow("Source");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile and how do you link your program? You probably have forgotten some library at link time, e.g. something like `-lopencv` or whatever. Order of libraries matters.

Comment: weel I have (in this order) #include <cv.h> #include <highgui.h> #include <1394camera.h>   I'm using eclipse so the libraries are imported setting the path of the compiler directly on eclipse. and in the project I can see the libraries I imported so I think they're ok

Comment: I was thining maybe about some .dll, but as I told you in the q394cmu there are only 2 dll and are in the project.

Comment: You should find out what compilation & linking commands are executed by Eclispe, and then you should fix them.

Comment: I don't know. But there is some way, and the question becomes Eclipse specific